# All-in-one +/-10" screen (not touch) w/ Linux, WiFi, USB, but w/o camera, mic

Tags: linux, all-in-one

I'm a developer by trade, but I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to the hardware side, so please forgive me if I am not detailed enough.

I would like to find an all-in-one (i.e., screen and OS in one unit) device to run a Linux distro. on (preferably pre-installed).  It will be used for digital, in-store advertising (for an example, see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PZWQ7QY)), so for security's sake, minimal functionality is important (details below).  What I have found on the market does not allow for any customization (i.e., access to the OS).

**Attributes:**

- Screen (preferably not touch) and OS in one unit
- 10" screen, give or take; some flexibility can be afforded here
- WiFi
- At least one USB port
- Does not need to be very powerful.  A Raspberry Pi 3 has tested to be sufficient
- Sound output preferred, but optional

**Cannot have:**

- Camera, microphone, or any other similar device capable of gathering information from the immediate environment
- Affixed keyboard

Comment: The 'cannot have" parts are tricky - most devices of the class of device you want are tablets and have those. You could get just a 10 inch monitor and a cheap SBC, but that dosen't quite meet the AIW requirement.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, that's been my experience.  I've considered tablets, but it absolutely cannot have a camera, and I've not been able to find one without.